# Why does AND on SQL update statement slow operation down?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [LB].[Orders]
(
    [OrderID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MasterOrderID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OrderID] ASC)
) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [PK_Index]  
    ON [BTP_NYA].[LB].[Orders] ([OrderDate]);
```

Why is update #1 much faster than update #2 ?

```
string newStaus = "Message";
long OrderID = 123;

// Update #1:
UPDATE [BTP_NYA].[XX].[Orders] 
SET [Status] = '" + newStatus + "' 
WHERE [OrderID] = " + orderID.ToString("0") + "";

// Update #2:
UPDATE [BTP_NYA].[XX].[Orders] 
SET [Status] = '" + newStatus + "' 
WHERE [OrderID] = " + orderID.ToString("0") + " 
  AND [Status] = 'NEW'
```

Update #1 takes 0-1 ms and Update #2 takes 7-8 ms

The only difference being that I check for `Status == 'NEW'` in update #2. I can't index status as that frequently changes value.

Comment: If you have many records and query on an unindexed field it gets slower - what is unusual about that?

Comment: 7-8ms seems pretty damn fast to me. If you want to improve the speed here add the status into your index

Comment: *I can't Index Status as that frequently changes value* It's update frequency might fragment the index, it does not mean you can't index it. Providing you maintain the index this shouldn't cause too big an issue.

Comment: @juergend Because OrderID is indexed and unique it should take exactly same amount of time to find record. The only difference is AFTER we found it whether to Update it

Comment: @Liam 7ms is very slow for this application

Comment: Have you tried working with SQL Parameters instead of building a completely new (at least for the SQL Server) Update Statement every time? Like: `UPDATE [BTP_NYA].[XX].[Orders] SET [Status] = @NewStatus WHERE [OrderID] = @OrderID AND [Status] = N'NEW'` -- (`N'NEW'` just because it's an *n*varchar field; shouldn't make a noticeable difference).

Comment: Btw. just tried it with that table and ~one million entries. Both versions as parameterized queries in the actual execution plan took 50 % each. With almost the exact same subtree costs.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this Update 1 much faster than Update 2

Update one is querying the table using it's primary key **only** `WHERE [OrderID] =`. this essentially is a binary tree search complexity of `O(log n)` (`n` being number of records in the table)

Update two is searching by the primary key **and another column**:

```
WHERE [OrderID] = " + orderID.ToString("0") + " AND [Status] = 'NEW'
```

It now can use the binary tree to get the values matching the order id (still `O(log n)`) but it must then traverse all these records to see which ones match `[Status]` of `"NEW"`. I'm not 100% sure how SQL will optimise this, I think it will still use the binary tree to match first then iterate these results, so complexity something like:

```
O((x=(log n)) * x)
```

Higher complexity = greater time to find the records.

But this will alter slightly depending on what SQL thinks is the most efficient way to optimise this query. If you include an execution plan you'll be able to see this.

Reference:

[Big O cheat cheeet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)